# How to get saves and progress from one machine to another Battle for Wesnoth?

Tags: 14.04, backup, preferences

Long story short, I'm on "new" ubuntu, but got external HDD with Ubuntu partition. Both are Ubuntu 14.04, maybe with different modifications. I think I broke this other Ubuntu (it was while ago, so I'm not sure), so booting external one is not an option.

What folders/files should I copy to my machine, to get my saved files, progress etc. (like crown for win in campaign) in Battle for Wesnoth.

I choose this one game because I can check if answer is right, and because I believe it's complicate enough, that everything else will work this way, but I would like to know general answer for problem like this. Is there any folder(s) which I can copy and be happy with terminator/emacs styles and plugins, TeX/LibreOffice fonts and dictionaries, Firefox/Chrome Bookmarks and pipelight? So LESS specific question, **what should I copy form one Ubuntu instance to another, to get my preferences**? I will check answer for specific Battle for Wesnoth, but would like to make question more open if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In linux, all your userdata is stored in you home, e. g. `/home/user`.  It's explained : [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_directory).
For BfW, there is an entry in the [wiki](http://wiki.wesnoth.org/EditingWesnoth#Linux_2).
I guess, if you copy `~/.local/share/wesnoth/`, it should work.

Comment: +1 for general answer (Thank you!), Battle for Wesnoth is not working right now, I haven't play it for months so I need to check whats the reason. Maybe this copy is not enough for BfW, will be back with answer later.

Comment: Maybe you should delete the folder on your new machine first. Also make sure, that you own all the files. If you copy them as root maybe, you must chown them to your user before starting the game.